# google script to add information to sheet , script and bootstrap form using showModalDialog

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I already have the html form made from bootstrap, however, when I am trying to use the click button to add the information to google sheet from the html form it is not working

this is my GS function

```
function addRow(rowData){
 
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("STUDENTS");
  ws.appendRow([rowData.names,rowData.phones,rowData.idnumber,rowData.fivehr]);

and this is my function on html file

function afterButtonClick(){
  var name = document.getElementById("studentnames");
  var phone = document.getElementById("phonenumber");
  var idnumber = document.getElementById("ID-number");
  var fivehr = document.getElementById("fivehr");
  var rowData = {name: name.value,phone: phone.value, idnumber: idnumber.value, fivehr: fivehr.value};
  google.script.run.addRow(rowData);

}

document.getElementById("ADD").addEvenListener("click",afterButtonClick);
```

example for the line for the variable

```
<input style="font-weight:bold" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Student Name" aria-label="Name" id="studentnames">
```

the html form is perfect the way I want it, but the function on html is not adding the data to sheet

I am following a youtuber but it is not working at all, I did some changes on the wording but I guess I am missing something, if anyone can look at it and tell me my mistake, I appreciate the help thank you

Comment: .addEvenListemer is misspelled, it should be .addEventListener

Comment: @LauraDye yeah I did the correction still no working, it is not sending the data information to the spreadsheet, thx you

Comment: What's keeping you from debugging it?

Comment: What errors are you getting? @Spec3

Answer (score 1):

if fivehr is a datetime then that is a restricted parameter and cannot be passed using google.script.run.  If it is a restricted parameter then the entire object will  be nulled out.  Read about it below:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#parameters_and_return_values

Comment: there is not datetime parameter on fivehr

Answer (score 0):

Keys of your object should be same.
You've to use `rowData.name` and `rowData.phone`.

> ws.appendRow([rowData.name,rowData.phone,rowData.idnumber,rowData.fivehr]);

In order to see what is the problem, you can firstly go to `DevTools > Console` and see if there is an error message in your client side functions. If not you go to `Script Editor > Executions` and see if your server side functions returned an exception.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Spec 3. Could you try my suggestion?